# Connect database in MS Access with Android

Tags: android, database, ms-access, database-connection

I will start to develop an application on Android and I need to access a database in MS Access. Is it possible to make the connection between MS Access and Android? How?

Comment: Through a webService. Set a server which provides access to a web-aware app which does the CRUD operations server side and just pass it the needed parameters. You'll then be able to get the results of the queries as well as modify the db contents.

Comment: You leaving out the details as to where this file resides. Access is a file based system. So you don’t connect to word, or your don’t connect to power-point, and you don’t connect to Access. You OPEN a word file, you OPEN a power-point file. You have to provide MORE information as to where the location of this file is, but you cannot “connect” to a Access mdb/accDB file no more then you connect to a power-point file.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try start creating a Restful-Service which will make you able to make the connection between your application and your server (where you have your dB).

There are tons of articles out there of how to start making it, here there is given an example for a microsoft SQL server( which can be useful to connect with your MS Access):

http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible by using "Jackcess" library.

Comment: Please add more detail.